# Problems using \tiny, \small etc

Tags: fonts, size

When I use the `\Tiny`, `\tiny`, `\SMALL`, `\Small` etc. commands, I am getting an undefined control sequence error.  My preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
```

Help please?

Comment: Some of those aren't default declarations. Only `\tiny` is provided by default, does it work for you? The others aren't defined

Comment: @campa Well, they define all the standard ones. No class defines all possible ones.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Where did you "learn" that `\Tiny`, `\Small`, and `\SMALL` are valid commands? It's true that there's `\Large` (and even `\LARGE`) and `\Huge` in addition to `\large` and `\huge`. However, this extension doesn't carry over to relative font sizes *smaller* than `\normalsize`.

Comment: The commands `\Tiny`, `\Small` and `\SMALL` are defined by the AMS classes (for instance, `amsart`), not in `article`.

Comment: @campa I meant that your comment is true of all actual and possible classes (assuming classes to be necessarily finite). When you say 'X only defines some', the obvious question is 'what about the rest?' But there is no well-defined set of 'all' font size commands, except that, as Au101 notes, there is a set of default font size commands, which the standard classes define by definition.

Answer (score 6):

Font size commands are provided by classes. The standard LaTeX classes provide

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

Beyond these (or, in a non-standard class, potentially including some of these), you need a non-standard class, a third-party package or a custom definition.

Note, too, that - as the above list suggests - command names are case-sensitive. In your subject, you ask about problems using `\tiny` and `\small`. This is puzzling, since both of these should work fine with a standard class such as `article`.

But in the body of your question, you ask about `\Tiny`, `\tiny`, `\SMALL` and `\Small`, of which only one is defined by the class you have chosen to use for your document. The others, therefore, are undefined.

Also, it may be worth saying that these are font sizes for text. Fonts are configured quite differently for mathematics, not excepting font sizing.